# How to show messages only few members?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/samples/scala/websocket-chat/app/models/ChatRoom.scala

I am use this project in this message is shown to all members. where i want so show this only few member from available members.

Comment: Do you have a list/set/array/seq of the members that you want to send the messages to?

Comment: i have set of members.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

1. filter in the actor and have separate broadcast channels for separate groups, this is probably best modeled with separate actors for the separate sets of broadcast 'groups'
2. filter the enumerator in the controller and have one broadcast
3. let everything out to the client and filter there in the receiving javascript

What option fits your problem best depends on your requirements. 3 is easiest to do, 2 is also pretty easy and never lets data out to the client that the client isn't meant to see (You can use Enumeratee.filter and run the messages enumerator through that and only let through messages that the client should see) while 1 might be the most 'correct' model of the problem.